# SQL grouping based on order and value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table

```
loctype    order
ACUTE      1
ACUTE      2
COM        3
COM        4
ACUTE      5
COM        6
```

I want a query that will apply rankings to groups in order, so my desired outcome is:

```
loctype    order    group_order
ACUTE      1        1
ACUTE      2        1
COM        3        2
COM        4        2
ACUTE      5        3
COM        6        4
```

Is there a way to do this as a SQL query without resorting to cursors?

Comment: What defines a group here?

Answer (score 1):

One method for achieving this is a difference of `row_number()` to identify the groups and then `dense_rank()` on the minimum value.  The code looks like:

```
select t.*, dense_rank(minid) over (order by minid) as group_order
from (select t.*, min(id) over (partition by loctype, grp) as minid
      from (select t.*
                   (row_number() over (order by [order]) -
                    row_number() over (partition by loctype order by [order])
                   ) as grp
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Another method (for SQL Server 2012+) is to use `lag()` with a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when loctype = prev_loctype then 0 else 1 end) over
           (order by id) as group_order
from (select t.*, lag(loctype) over (order by id) as prev_loctype
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The top solution didn't quite work as desired, and threw up some undesired outcomes, however it pointed me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the given solution for SQL Server 2008 (that's what I have to work with). Unfortunately it didn't give quite the correct results, however working from Gordon's example, I came up with this, which does give exactly the desired result.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (       
        SELECT
            *,
            DENSE_RANK() over(order by (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(#tmp.[order]),0) FROM #tmp WHERE #tmp.[order]<t.[order] AND #tmp.loctype <> t.loctype)) as intorder
        FROM
            #tmp AS t
    ) AS u
```

This gives

```
loctype order group_order
ACUTE   1     1
ACUTE   2     1
COM     3     2
COM     4     2
ACUTE   5     3
COM     6     4
```

Essentially it hides an initial ordering inside the DENSE_RANK(). Without the DENSE_RANK() it looks like this:

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
             (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(#tmp.[order]),0) FROM #tmp WHERE #tmp.[order] t.loctype) as intgroup
        FROM
            #tmp AS t
    ) AS u

And gives this result:

```
loctype order   intgroup
ACUTE   1       0
ACUTE   2       0
COM     3       2
COM     4       2
ACUTE   5       4
COM     6       5
```

The interim group order can then be DENSE_RANKed to give the desired outcome.